# Dropdown triggered from on hovering an element already existing in a dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am kinda new to Web Development, so I am struggling with a pretty basic problem (I suppose). I have a bootstrap navigation bar, containing multiple dropdown buttons (dropdown activates on hover). On one of my buttons from one of the dropdowns, I need another dropdown that activates on hovering over 'Perioadele'. I am kinda stuck here because I am not completely familiarized with the html language.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Bitter;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 150px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 240px;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 15px;">
      <button class="dropbtn">ROREG</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <a href="#">Istoric</a>
        <a href="#">Valoare propusa</a>
        <a href="#">Conducere</a>
        <a href="#">Responsabilitate sociala</a>
        <a href="#">Cariera</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 5%;">
      <button class="dropbtn">FONDURI EUROPENE</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="height: 132px; margin-left: 20px;">
        <a href="#">Catalog</a>
        <a href="#">Perioadele</a>
        <a href="#">Regulamente europene</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made something that fulfills your requirement.

This opens an additional menu when you hover over `<a>Perioadele</a>`

Try it

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Bitter;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 150px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 240px;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.perioadele-content {
    display: none;
}

.perioadele-content:hover {
     display: block;
}

.pd:hover + .perioadele-content {
    display: block;
}


.pd:hover::after  + .perioadele-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 15px;">
      <button class="dropbtn">ROREG</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <a href="#">Istoric</a>
        <a href="#">Valoare propusa</a>
        <a href="#">Conducere</a>
        <a href="#">Responsabilitate sociala</a>
        <a href="#">Cariera</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 5%;">
      <button class="dropbtn">FONDURI EUROPENE</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="height: 132px; margin-left: 20px;">
        <a href="#">Catalog</a>
        <a href="#" class="pd" >Perioadele</a>
           <div class="perioadele-content dropdown-content" style="height: 132px; margin-left: 120px;">
            <a href="#">Perioadele A</a>
            <a href="#">Perioadele B</a>
            <a href="#">Perioadele C</a>
          </div>
        <a href="#">Regulamente europene</a>
      </div>
     
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well. The only problem is that as soon as I try to reach for one of "A" "V" "C" links, the dropdown disappears. I can't click on any link from the new dropdown.

Comment: Updated it. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a nice day.